# How to get the type of the values in a C++20 std::ranges range?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Given a `std::ranges::range` in C++20, how can I determine the type of the values in that range?

I want to write a function that makes a `std::vector` out of an arbitrary range. I'd like this function to have a nice, explicit declaration. Something like:

```
template<std::ranges::range Range>
std::vector<std::value_type_t<Range>> make_vector(Range const&);
```

The following seems to work, but the declaration is not explicit and the implementation is ugly (even ignoring that it doesn't allocate the right size up-front where possible).

```
  template<std::ranges::range Range>
  auto make_vector(Range const& range)
  {
    using IteratorType = decltype(std::ranges::begin(std::declval<Range&>()));
    using DerefType    = decltype(*std::declval<IteratorType>());
    using T            = std::remove_cvref_t<DerefType>;
    std::vector<T> retval;
    for (auto const& x: range) {
      retval.push_back(x);
    }
    return retval;
  }
```

Is there a canonical/better/shorter/nicer way to do this?

Comment: @user17732522 that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Sidenote, there's also `iter_value_t` to get you from iterator types to value types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this in order:

```cpp
template<std::ranges::range Range>
auto make_vector(Range const& range)
```

This is checking if `Range` is a range, but `range` isn't a `Range`, it's a `const Range`. It's possible that `R` is a `range` but `R const` is not, so you're not actually constraining this function properly.

The correct constraint would be:

```cpp
template<typename Range>
    requires std::ranges::range<Range const>
auto make_vector(Range const& range)
```

But then that limits you to only const-iterable ranges (which is an unnecessary restriction) and then requires you to very carefully use `Range const` throughout the body (which is very easy to forget).

Both of which are why, with ranges, you'll want to use forwarding references:

```cpp
template<std::ranges::range Range>
auto make_vector(Range&& range)
```

That'll constrain your function properly.

---

Next:

```cpp
using IteratorType = decltype(std::ranges::begin(std::declval<Range&>()));
using DerefType    = decltype(*std::declval<IteratorType>());
using T            = std::remove_cvref_t<DerefType>;
```

There are type traits for these things directly:

```cpp
using IteratorType = std::ranges::iterator_t<Range>;
using DerefType = std::iter_reference_t<IteratorType>;
```

Or:

```cpp
using DerefType = std::ranges::range_reference_t<Range>;
```

But also since you want the value type, that's (as already pointed out):

```cpp
using T = std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>;
```

Note that the value type is not necessarily just the reference type with the qualifiers removed.

---

Lastly:

```cpp
std::vector<T> retval;
for (auto const& x: range) {
    retval.push_back(x);
}
return retval;
```

It'll be more efficient or even more correct to forward the element into `push_back` (i.e. `auto&& x` and then `FWD(x)`, instead of `auto const& x` and `x`).

---

Additionally you'll want to, at the very least:

```cpp
if constexpr (std::ranges::sized_range<Range>) {
    retval.reserve(std::ranges::size(range));
}
```

Since if we have the size readily available, it'll be nice to reduce the allocations to just the one.

---

Lastly, in C++23, `make_vector(r)` can just be spelled `std::ranges::to<std::vector>(r)`. This does the allocation optimization I mentioned, but can additionally be more performant since `vector`'s construction internally can avoid the constant checking to see if additional allocation is necessary (which is what `push_back` has to do).

Comment: "*This is checking if `Range` is a `range`, but `range` isn't a `Range`, it's a `const Range`.*" Well... yeah. You want the compiler to be able to stop you if you do non-`const` stuff with it. That is all as it should be.

Comment: @NicolBolas OP has the wrong constraint, they're checking if `R` is a `range` but they're using `R const` as a `range` - `range<R>` does not imply `range<R const>`. There are types for which the former is true but not the latter (which would mean the constraint passes but then the instantiation still fails). OP can't do non-`const` stuff with it (short of `const_cast` I guess).

Comment: It's possible that a `Range const` might not be a range even when `Range` is. But the way to correct that is to make the constraint check `range<R const>`. Using `Range&&` means the function now takes incoherent `Range` types that don't provide `const` access, as well as allowing you to modify those ranges accidentally.

Comment: @NicolBolas (a) as noted in the answer (b) the canonical way to use ranges is with forwarding references - `R const&` doesn't make the range [deep const](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/09/10/deep-const/) anyway, if you want to ensure the elements aren't modified, you need something like [`views::as_const`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2278r4.html). Views aren't deep const, so even for those views that are const-iterable, `R const&` is just an illusion anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The type trait you are looking for is spelled [`std::ranges::range_value_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t), not `std::value_type_t`.

Also, the whole function you are trying to write here is just a more limited version of [`std::ranges::to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to) coming in C++23.